# Optimizing speed for bulk SSL API requests

Tags: python, api

I have written a script to run around 530 API calls which i intend to run every 5 minutes, from these calls i store data to process in bulk later (Prediction ETC).

The API has a limit of 500 requests per second. However when running my code I am seeing a 2 second time per call (due to SSL i believe).

How can i speed this up to enable me to run 500 requests within 5 minutes, as the current time required renders the data i am collecting useless :(

Code:

```
def getsurge(lat, long):

    response = client.get_price_estimates(
                    start_latitude=lat,
                    start_longitude=long,
                    end_latitude=-34.063676,
                    end_longitude=150.815075
            )

    result = response.json.get('prices')

    return result

def writetocsv(database):
    database_writer = csv.writer(database)
    database_writer.writerow(HEADER)

    pool = Pool()

# Open Estimate Database
    while True:

        for data in coordinates:
            line = data.split(',')

            long = line[3]
            lat = line[4][:-2]

            estimate = getsurge(lat, long)

            timechecked = datetime.datetime.now()

            for d in estimate:
                if d['display_name'] == 'TAXI':
                    database_writer.writerow([timechecked, [line[0], line[1]], d['surge_multiplier']])
                    database.flush()
                    print(timechecked, [line[0], line[1]], d['surge_multiplier'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the APi under your control? If so, create an endpoint which can give you all the data you need in one go.

Comment: It is not under my control.